# When a (slack) bot is made to leave a channel, how can I get an event in the bot telling it this has happened?

Tags: slack-api

When a (slack) bot is made to leave a channel, how can I get an event in the bot telling it this has happened?  I'm already handling member_left_channel  but when I remove the bot from the channel, it doesn't get this event (probably because the bot is already out of the channel when the event is triggered to flow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your app is subscribed to `member_left_channel` on behalf of the bot user event. On your app's configuration site, go to **Event Subscriptions** and select `member_left_channel` under **Subscribe to events on behalf of users**.If you subscribe to `member_left_channel` under the authenticated user instead, as long as the user is in the channel, you should get an event when the bot leaves the channel. In most cases, unless your app is configured to support OAuth, the only authenticated user will be you so make sure you're in the channel.

Comment: I end up using the `channel_left` event for public channels and `group_left` event for private channels.

Comment: This actually doesn't work if the bot itself is leaving the channel. It is only firing the `channel_left` event and not the `member_left_channel` for the bot, I think it has to do with the fact that `member_left_channel` and `member_joined_channel` events only come for the channels the bot is a part of.

I checked the behaviour with a regular non bot user (while my bot was in the channel) and I was getting the `member_left_channel` event